# Storing to and loading from a field in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, field

I need to store the outer-height of every `<p>` element inside `<div>` with a certain class in my page and then use it on each wrapping `<div>` as the negative margin.

But every `<p>` has different height because of different text.

```
<div margin="negative outerHeight of <p>">
     <p>I need this outer height</p>
</div>

<div margin="negative outerHeight of <p>">
     <p>I need this outer height so much</p>
</div>

<div margin="negative outerHeight of <p>">
     <p>I need this outer height to destroy the world</p>
</div>
```

I was thinking to go over every `<p>` and store it in a field. And then load the height from the field. The problem is that I don't know how to write this in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function overload of [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/). This assumes there is only one `<p>` child element:

```
$("div").css("margin", function() {
    return "-" + $(this).find("p:first-child").outerHeight() + "px";
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/2auBa/)